# How to print All rows in jtable

Tags: java, jtable, rowcount

example data:
These are my 2 rows in jtable

```
[john, carter, post, add]
[smith, sale, col, late]


  for (int count = 0; count < dataModel.getRowCount(); count++){
  data.add(dataModel.getValueAt(count, 0).toString());
   }
  System.out.println(data);
```

When I run this code i get output:

```
[john, smith]
```

My question is how can i print the entire row rather than just the first column.
So the output should be:

```
[john, carter, post, add]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print the entire table you'll need two loops, one for the rows, one for the columns:

```
for (int row = 0; row < dataModel.getRowCount(); row++){
    for (int column = 0; column < dataModel.getColumnCount(); column++){
        data.add(dataModel.getValueAt(row, column).toString());
    }
    // Probably add new line to 'data'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DefaultTableModel` you can get all table data by [getDataVector()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector()):

> Returns the Vector of Vectors that contains the table's data values.
>   The vectors contained in the outer vector are each a single row

Retrieve a vector representing a single row by `(Vector)getDataVector().elementAt(rowNumber)`